# Multiple fallback languages in Nestjs i18n

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, nestjs

I'm using [nestjs-i18n](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n) to handle translations in my APIs.

At the moment, my app handles **en** as the default language. However, I want to fallback **en** in case of receiving en-**US**, en-**GB**, en-**IE** and so on.

Is it possible to fallback a specific language when receiving multiple variations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened an issue [#138](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n/issues/138) regarding this case and it is already closed.

Also, I sent a PR to create an additional feature to this library so we can configure multiple fallback languages from version [V8.0.5](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n/releases/tag/V8.0.5).

Essentially, it is as simple as:

```js
I18nModule.forRoot({
  fallbackLanguage: 'en',
  fallbacks: {
    'en-*': 'en',
    'fr-*': 'fr',
    'pt-PT': 'pt-BR',
    'pt': 'pt-BR',
  },
  ...
});
```

Hope I could help you guys. Cheers

Comment: Hi could you please share with me how to implement the middleware to get the request-header and importantly to use that language in our whole application only with the translation key without specifying the language folder names